# How to remove byte order mark from a python text from clipboard?

Tags: python, encoding, byte-order-mark

Here is the code I'm using to put a text in the clipboard:

```
def SetClipboard(text): #taken from pyperclip for windows
    text = str(text)
    GMEM_DDESHARE = 0x2000
    ctypes.windll.user32.OpenClipboard(0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text))+1)  # @UndefinedVariable
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text, 'ascii'))+1)  # @UndefinedVariable
    pchData = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalLock(hCd)  # @UndefinedVariable
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text))
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text, 'ascii'))
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hCd)  # @UndefinedVariable
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetClipboardData(1, hCd)
    ctypes.windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

However when someone pastes the data, he gets some invisible bytes at the start of the text that invalidate the input. How can I get rid of them?